# Upload image in symfony form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

I am having a weird problem. I added an upload image field to a form. Every thing work fine when i use this code in the twig file

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
<button>d</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

But when ever i want to use form_widget to costumize the look of the form this error appear when ever i try to sumit the form

> FatalErrorException
>   Error: Call to a member function getFileName() on string.

This is the View that cause the problem

```
{% extends 'BridgeTravelBundle:Admin:layout.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="x_panel">
            <form method="POST" id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Nom</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        {{ form_widget(form.name, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Prenom' } }) }}
                        {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Icon</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        {{ form_widget(form.icon, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Prenom' } }) }}
                        {{ form_errors(form.icon) }}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Icon</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        {{ form_widget(form.file) }}
                        {{ form_errors(form.file) }}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                        <button class="btn btn-success">Valider</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock body %}
```

This is the Action that control the form.

```
public function addCategoryAction(Request $request){

        $category=new Category();
        $form=$this->createForm(CategoryType::class,$category);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted())
        {
            $image= $form['file']->getData();
            $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $req = $request->request->get('Bridge_TravelBundle_Category');
            $category->setName($req['name']);
            $category->setIcon($req['icon']);
            $name = $req['name'];
            try {
                if(!is_dir("CategoriesPictures")){
                    mkdir("CategoriesPictures");
                }

                move_uploaded_file($image,"CategoriesPictures/".$image->getFileName());
                rename("CategoriesPictures/".$image->getFileName() , "CategoriesPictures/".$name.".jpg");

            }
            catch (IOExceptionInterface $e) {
                echo "Erreur Profil existant ou erreur upload image ".$e->getPath();
            }

            $em->persist($category);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_categories');
        }

        return $this->render("BridgeTravelBundle:Admin:addcategory.html.twig",array('form' => $form->createView(),));
    }
```

This the CategoryType.php

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class CategoryType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name')
            ->add('icon')
            ->add('file',FileType::class, array(
                    'multiple'    => false,
                    'attr' => array(

                        'accept' => 'image/*',
                    )
                )
            )       ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Bridge\TravelBundle\Entity\Category'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'Bridge_TravelBundle_Category';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your CategoryType class and dump data of $image

Comment: @HoangND i added the CategoryType and this is wha var_dump($image) return: C:\wamp64\www\BridgeTravel\src\Bridge\TravelBundle\Controller\AdminController.php:207:string '3.jpg' (length=5)

Comment: I think you are missing this: enctype='multipart/form-data' in form tag
You should just use form_start & form_end instead of manually put form tag.
If you need to add attributes to form tag you can do it with form_start anyway

Comment: Here is how you can add attributes for form
{{ form_start(form, { 'attr': {'class': 'foo', 'id': 'bar', ... } }) }}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This attribute `enctype='multipart/form-data'` is missing from your `form` tag.

You should just you `form_start` & `form_end` instead writing `form` tag by yourself.

You can also put custom attributes with `form_start` function like this

```
{{ form_start(form, { 'attr': {'class': 'foo', 'id': 'bar' } }) }}
```

Also, `form_end` is very important because it also print out `form_rest` and any missing field.

```
<form method="POST" id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
```

will become

```
{{ form_start(form, { 'attr': { 'id': 'demo-form2', 'data-parsley-validate': null, 'class': 'form-horizontal form-label-left' } }) }}
```

and

```
</form>
```

will become

```
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: i have another question and i hope you can help me, do you know how can i make that form upload multiple images at once? right now it upload just one image and when i change 'multiple' => true and i try to upload images i get an error "Expected argument of type "string", "array" given"

Comment: You need to use CollectionType try something like this:

$builder->add('pictures', CollectionType::class, [
        'type' => FileType::class
]);

Comment: Ok i made the change  and added that line in the CategoryType but it doesn't show "choose files" in the View so i can't upload files! please help me

Comment: The reason it's not showing anything is because by default the collection is empty. You can implement add button to add more file inputs

If you are using mopa bootstrap bundle, check this out 
http://bootstrap.mohrenweiserpartner.de/mopa/bootstrap/forms/collections

Otherwise, check Symfony guide on collection type.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html